# GoogleSignInAccount not logged in

Tags: android, google-signin, google-play-games

**OnActivityResult**

```
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task =
                        GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);

                try {
                    GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    onConnected(account);
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setMessage("All ok")
                            .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                            .show();
                } catch (ApiException apiException) {
                    String message = apiException.getMessage();
                    if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                        message = "Error";
                    }

                    onDisconnected();

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setMessage(message)
                            .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                            .show();
                }
            }
```

**Button**

```
private void startSignInIntent() {
        startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
```

**SILENT SIGN IN**

```
 private void signInSilently() {

    Log.d("123", "signInSilently()");

    mGoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d("123", "signInSilently(): success");
                        onConnected(task.getResult());
                    } else {
                        Log.d("123", "signInSilently(): failure", task.getException());
                        onDisconnected();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

**START ACTIVITY**

```
  mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build());
```

When I click on the "authorization" button, I can register an account, but after registration an error is generated **4:**, I looked through the documentation and did not find what this means, it is possible that I'm just blind. Help the poor how to solve it and what it is

Comment: Could you provide the error?

Comment: I learned that the error is referred to as SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, but it did not help me much. Where to report?

Comment: Same thing happens to me. Have you managed to solve?

Comment: Yes, in my case it was that my version code was outdated and I did not consider it. I updated the version code and filled in the alpha closed access to the play console, and everything worked out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I updated VERSION CODE to the newest one and loaded the play console into the closed alpha access, everything worked**